# Remote detection of spring framework

Tags: web-application, http, spring-framework

I would like to know if there is a remote way to understand if a web app uses the Spring framework. In particular Spring security.

Is there any kind of analysis on HTTP headers that can provide information about it?

Comment: If you can get the app to expose stack traces it should be pretty easy to spot spring security filters in the stack.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Security.SE. :)

Yes, there are a few things you can do to find Spring Framework, or more specifically Spring Boot. Spring Security is a little more awkward, but you can look for `/login` and see what it does. Here's some things I do:

- favicon. The green leaf is a dead giveaway.
- `/env` and `/health` (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html) or if using the newer Spring Actuator, `/actuator/env` and `/actuator/health`

Aside from that, look at the HTML responses. Especially on `/login`. It has a boilerplate response.

Comment: Would this be considered a type of fingerprinting then?

Comment: Yes. :) Just a question of where. Some applications have dead giveaways in response headers (`X-Powered-By`, for example), while others have standard CSS bundlers, like with Ruby on Rails framework.